# Save data with LINQ

Tags: string, datetime

I've create object with data type: DateTime
But I want save as char data type in sql server

ex: assign value to obj property:
MyDateTime=DateTime.Now;
//when use to string method result: MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
//save to db MyDateTime column with data type char(12)
we will save: MM/dd/yyyy

How can I save it.
I try use assign converter attribute to property but does not effect

Update: 2010/09/24 13:36
Ex:
DataContext data=new DataContext();
MyObject obj=new MyObject();
obj.MyDate=DateTime.Now;
data.MyObjects.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
data.SubmitChange();

property's data type of object is: DateTime
column in db is char(12)

how can I format it or write custom attribute to format data before save to db

Answer (score 0):

Use a string formatter:

```
string dateString = MyDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

And write that value to the Database.

For other examples, have a look here:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/